# How will log in to aws account if MFA enabled mobile get lost or damage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a aws account and enabled the MFA for root user. By chance, if my phone got damaged or stolen then how will I login to my aws account with root user because it will ask for MFA.

Any IAM user can login to console but it can not disable the MFA for root user even this user has "Administrator Access".

Is there any way to login to aws account if MFA enabled device got lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the phone number and email address associated with the AWS root account, you can go through an automated process of verifying you're the account owner, deactivating your MFA, logging in w/out MFA, and activating a new MFA virtual device. More info at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/reset-your-aws-root-accounts-lost-mfa-device-faster-by-using-the-aws-management-console/

As mentioned in the blog post, if you don't have access to the phone number for the root account or didn't associate a phone number with your root account when you signed up, you'll have to contact AWS support and have access to your email address that's associated with the AWS root account.

You could avoid all of this by making a copy of your MFA QR code and storing it in a secure place, like a fireproof safe, and setting up a new virtual device with your stored QR code without having to perform any interventions to deactivate your AWS root account's existing MFA activation.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the AWS support and explain the situation. They may provide the verification code to the "email" that you have registered on creating the AWS account.